# Admin Sales Orders template

Tags: ce-1.4.0.1

Using Magento Community 1.4.0.1
In the Admin Sales Orders template, I have set the row heights and column widths to be able to show more data like this:

[image]

Now, I want to set an anchor tag for the order number. This is what gets set to the TITLE attribute, I want to create an 
anchor so that I can right click and open in another tab.
This is a sample of the title attribute value:
`%store_url%/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/141799/key/0fab5c58e60debb542519cbe0879a857/`

How/where would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/store/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml`
approx line 164:

```
<?php echo (($_html = $_column->getRowField($_item)) != '' ? $_html : '&nbsp;') ?>
```

Change to this:

```
<?php 
    $_html = $_column->getRowField($_item);
    if($i == 2) { // this is the second column in the grid with the order#
        $_html = '<a href="'.$this->getRowId($_item).'">'.$_html.'</a>';
    }
    echo ($_html != '' ? $_html : '&nbsp;') 
?>
```

Then you get the anchor link on the order#

[image]